# C++ shows '123', 3224115 in output (using cout)

Tags: c++, char, literals

this is my c++ homework, please help me. (I already googled it and found nothing)

```
int main()
{
    std::cout<<'123';
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

in output you'll get 3224115.
why?

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes. ' is for a single character not a string. Use double quote " for a string. `std::cout<<"123";`

Comment: I know. the question is what exactly I wrote.

Comment: Look at the hexadecimal representation of 3224115. Then look in an ASCII table for the hexadecimal representation of the digits.

Comment: @molbdnilo please explain more a little bit.

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you :)

Comment: @MartinJames thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Write instead

```
std::cout << "123";
             ^   ^
```

`'123'` is a character literal that has implementation defined value and type `int`.

It can be imagine for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x = 0x313233;

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

where `0x31`, `0x32`, `0x33` are ASCII codes for characters `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` correspondingly.

For this program the output can be

```
3224115
```

Comment: I mustn't change the single quote. I have to find out why I get that number in out put.

Comment: @PaladinVahid As I wrote multibyte character literal has type int. Its value is implementation defined

Comment: I think you miss understood the question. the question is why we getting that number not what is wrong with the code.

Comment: I need to know why '123' shown 3224115 by compiler.

Comment: @PaladinVahid, than ask your compiler vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (pg 61)

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>   implementation-defined.

Comment: I think you miss understood the question. the question is why we getting that number not what is wrong with the code.

Comment: I need to know why '123' shown 3224115 by compiler.

Comment: Edited to show why the single quotes don't work